# Только вертикальное отображение webview

Tags: java, android, html, eclipse

Как заставить отображаться содержимое WebView только вертикально? Так, будто мы перевернули телефон на альбомный.

Пробовал прописать в .xml WebView - `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.
Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: А вообще не очень понятно что имеете в виду под "заставить отображаться содержимое WebView только вертикально". Может, вы хотите в разной ориентации экрана разное поведение... Раскройте суть вопроса так, как будто вы это объясняете своему коту/пятилетнему ребёнку.

Comment: Нужно чтобы WebView отображался так, как будто мы взяли телефон и положили его горизонтально, и он у нас  автоматически перевернулся (т.е. ширина увеличчилась высота уменьшилась).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам надо просто повернуть ваш элемент разметки:

1. В размтке:

`android:rotation="90.0"`

2. В коде:

`webView.setRotation(90.0f);`

Comment: Видимо - нет), так как вы сказали - не корректно отображается содержимое WebView, хотя если просто повернуть телефон то все хорошо отображается. UPD На android версии 2.3.4 вообще ничего не изменилось

Comment: @LorDo, под "некорректно" что имеете в виду?.. То, что отображаемый HTML код, с заданными в пикселях размерами элементов, имеет "поехавшую" вёрстку, не отвечает вашим ожиданиям о мастабировании элементов разметки или просто вообще ничего не отображается? Будьте добры выражаться предельно конкретно - слова типа "ничего не работает" не поможет решить к-л проблему кроме как советом типа "перезагрузите комп **n** раз"

Comment: Ну похоже перевернулся сам WebView но при этом не произошел перерисовка (пере расчет высоты и ширины) поэтому содержимое оказалось за пределом экрана

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете, например, в Activity в нужный момент принудительно выставить ориентацию в вертикальную:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: До но это какбы костыль.... разве по другому никак?

Comment: @LorDo, нет, как бы не костыль. Если хотите сделать *правильно*, то адаптируйте содержимое `WebView` Для landscape-ориентации.

Comment: Так содержимое прекрасно ориентировано, само приложение сделано под портретную ориентацию, а WebView требуется показать в альбомной, и показывается он не долго, и получается так что сначала я меняю ориентацию на альбомную "вручную" командой, а потом обратно на портретную через маленькое количество времени, все таки я думаю можно задать альбомную ориентацию для WebView отдельно и не играться с этими командами.